# How how convert normal string into multi-line string

Tags: arrays, string, formatting, multilinestring

How can i convert string in to formatted string

**Following String i have**

> `"It was the best of times, it was the worst of times,
>   it was the age of wisdom, it was the age of foolishness,
>   it was the epoch of belief, it was the epoch of incredulity,
>   it was the season of Light, it was the season of Darkness,
>   it was the spring of hope, it was the winter of despair,
>   we had everything before us, we had nothing before us"`

**I have to convert above String like this**

```
"It was the best of times, it was the worst of times,\\n" +
" it was the age of wisdom, it was the age of foolishness,\\n" +
" it was the epoch of belief, it was the epoch of incredulity,\\n" +
" it was the season of Light, it was the season of Darkness,\\n" +
" it was the spring of hope, it was the winter of despair,\\n" +
" we had everything before us, we had nothing before us";
```

Comment: hm, as you did not state a programming language - just the basics: most languages offer a `split()` command - or you use `replace()`... to replace a normal line break ( \n ) with `" + \n"`

Comment: This is usually done by means of text editor, most of the advanced ones support regexp find/replace and macros.

Comment: @Najzero thanks and i used .replace("\n", "\\n"); but not wok properly

Answer (score 0):

Just add an escape sequence with a `\r\n` instead of `+` in your string. See also : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx

```
"It was the best of times, it was the worst of times,\r\n
  it was the age of wisdom, it was the age of foolishness,\r\n
  it was the epoch of belief, it was the epoch of incredulity,\r\n
  it was the season of Light, it was the season of Darkness,\r\n
  it was the spring of hope, it was the winter of despair,\r\n
  we had everything before us, we had nothing before us"
```

or use Environment.NewLine Property like

```
"It was the best of times, it was the worst of times," + Environment.NewLine
+ " it was the age of wisdom, it was the age of foolishness," + Environment.NewLine 
+ " it was the epoch of belief, it was the epoch of incredulity," + Environment.NewLine 
+ " it was the season of Light, it was the season of Darkness," + Environment.NewLine 
+ " it was the spring of hope, it was the winter of despair," + Environment.NewLine  
+ " we had everything before us, we had nothing before us"
```

Comment: thanks for replying  but im using java and jeson String